# Returning an object in the stack by value

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

When I have an object allocated not dinamically and I return it by value:

```
string get()
{
    string str("hello");
    return str;
}
```

There are chances to get memory leak? I make some examples:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string str=get(); // case 1
    get();              // case 2
    string* ptr=&get();    // case 3
}
```

In which cases there's a memory leak?

Comment: Why would you think there's a memory leak?

Comment: str in get() isn't allocated in the heap, it's on the stack.
But when returning a value there's a copy of the object as left operand of the assignment.Expecially in the case where there isn't a left operant (case 2), I don't know where this object copied goes, is it destroyed?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: In case 2, the returned object is a *temporary*, which is destroyed at the end of the expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no memory leaks, but case 3 isn't even vaguely valid.

The `get()` function returns a copy of the string, possibly optimized, since `std::string` is a class and not a pointer or anything else. It works, from the user's point of view, roughly the same as returning an `int` from a function: a copy is created and returned, and stays valid outside of the function scope so as to allow assignment or use. Without that behavior, return values in general wouldn't be possible.

It applies to PODs and classes very similarly (although the class needs a copy constructor and such). You should be able to do this for almost any `std` class, although the cost of making a copy will vary (it's a bad idea to return a `std::vector<BigClass>(1000)`, for example). Depending on settings, your compiler may be able to optimize the copy away through RVO.

**Case 1** uses that: the copy is assigned to `str`, no memory leak, no problem. Pretty simple.

**Case 2** discards the copy, but still, no problems.

**Case 3** will try to take the address of the temporary return value, which will quickly be destroyed by the compiler (due to being unused) and make `ptr` a hanging pointer. Any use of `ptr` after the temporary is gone will cause undefined behavior, probably an access violation. Where and when the temporary will be destroyed will depend on your compiler, settings, and other things you can't rely on.

The correct form is **1** (although **2** is also valid, just not very useful).

Comment: I think you're right that case 3 won't compile, but for the wrong reason.

Comment: I'm actually not entirely sure which way 3 will be compiled, so put in both possibilities until I can test it. Either way it's bad.

Comment: Case 3 compiles just fine, but I do get a "address of temporary" warning (testing with g++ 4.3.2 using -Wall). The `()` function call operator has higher precedence than `&`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not dynamically allocating any memory on the heap (use of `new` or `malloc` and friends) none of your examples will leak.

Comment: This assumes that the class you are creating has a proper destructor ;)

Comment: I thought about adding that, but since I am going to assume OP did not roll his own string class I omitted the details. Just important to realize once you write code that contains `new` or `malloc` you are responsible for its destruction or clearly documenting that the caller takes ownership of the object.

Comment: @GWW: Doesn't matter, the rule applies recursively. If the class doesn't use `new` either, then the class itself also won't leak.

Comment: Actually, I get only a warning for case 3.

Comment: @MSalters: I agree that it won't leak if the class doesn't use new, but if it did use new and didn't have a proper destructor there would be a leak.

Comment: I hate to be pedantic (who am I kidding, I love it...), but: If you call a function that take a reference to an object, and give it a temporary object, the object will last until the end of the expression, which includes the entire time spent inside the function. So inside the function you CAN take the address of the temporary. Although temporary is a point of view, and it isn't from the function's point of view... right? maybe? What about if the function takes a pointer? The temporary still lasts the entire expression right? So foo(&bar()) is valid? I think I'm just making it up now.

Comment: Well, I just tested them and both work, although gcc warns about foo(&bar()). Doesn't mean they're not UB though...

Answer (score 1):

For std classes and simple type there "should" never leak.  For you customs classes it is up to you to create a class that correctly allocates and deallocates its internal resources correctly.